# How can I collect `pslist` elapsed time information by using wmic?

Tags: powershell, wmic

The MS technet utility [`pslist`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx) can produce result like this:

[image]

How can I use wmic to obtain the 'Elapsed Time' result?

If it is not possible, I am happy to try Powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I get process 'Elapsed Time' result?

The following powershell command will display process elapsed time (in seconds):

```
(Get-Process | ft Name,@{label="Elapsed Time";expression={[System.Math]::Round(((Get-Date)-$_.StartTime).TotalSeconds)}})
```

Source [How to get total elapsed time of processes with PowerShell](http://www.yusufozturk.info/windows-powershell/how-to-get-total-elapsed-time-of-processes-with-powershell.html).

It subtracts the process start time from the current date ...

---

#### How do I convert seconds to hh:mm:ss?

If you want to convert the seconds to `hh:mm:ss` see StackOverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842175/powershell-convert-seconds-to-hhmmss-fff-format.